# update module name throughout a package after file is renamed

Tags: python, module, rename

I have 3 modules: `shape.py`, `size.py`, `color.py`. The `color.py` module has one function `make_blue()`.  Both `shape.py` and `size.py` import the module `color.py` and call the function (possibly several times) via `color.make_blue()`.  Later, I decide I need to change the name of `color.py` to `color_2.py`.  How do I update `shape.py` and `size.py` so that `color.make_blue()` is replaced with `color_2.make_blue()`?

What is the recommended way to handle this situation?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most IDE's have a "refactor - rename" option, you should look up the one relevant for your IDE. For instance, if you are using PyCharm, right click the module and click on `refactor` then `rename`, or use default key binding `Shift + F6`, this will then automatically scan through your project and update all references and calls (you can even change docstrings and comment mentions if you so desire).